# How to retract a message in ejabberd?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I'm creating a MUC client and I want to implement some kind of message deletion in the client. I read that deleting an individual message from ejabberd is not possible yet. But how can I use [XEP-0424](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0424.html#usecase) for the achieve a similar purpose? I've read, written and tested the use case described in that XEP, but no success.

The client send a message like this:

```html
<message xmlns="jabber:client" to="myroom@conference.localhost" type="groupchat">
   <body>9</body>
   <urls />
   <origin-id xmlns="urn:xmpp:sid:0" id="358f5b60-3d10-11ea-be33-5f58c62bedc3" />
</message>
```

The server broadcasts this:

```html
<message xmlns="jabber:client" to="user1@localhost/1132254315040517635831042" from="myroom@conference.localhost" id="1579690081679918">
   <archived xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:tmp" by="user1@localhost" id="1579690081690608" />
   <stanza-id xmlns="urn:xmpp:sid:0" by="user1@localhost" id="1579690081690608" />
   <event xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event">
      <items node="urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:messages">
         <item id="1579690081679918">
            <message xmlns="jabber:client" xml:lang="en" to="user1@localhost" from="myroom@conference.localhost/user1" type="groupchat">
               <archived xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:tmp" by="myroom@conference.localhost" id="1579690081679918" />
               <stanza-id xmlns="urn:xmpp:sid:0" by="myroom@conference.localhost" id="1579690081679918" />
               <urls />
               <origin-id xmlns="urn:xmpp:sid:0" id="358f5b60-3d10-11ea-be33-5f58c62bedc3" />
               <body>9</body>
            </message>
         </item>
      </items>
   </event>
</message>
```

Retraction message sent:

```html
<message xmlns="jabber:client" to="myroom@conference.localhost" type="groupchat">
   <apply-to xmlns="urn:xmpp:fasten:0" id="358f5b60-3d10-11ea-be33-5f58c62bedc3">
      <retract xmlns="urn:xmpp:message-retract:0" />
   </apply-to>
</message>
```

As result of the retraction message sent, the server broadcasts this:

```html
<message xmlns="jabber:client" to="user1@localhost/1132254315040517635831042" from="myroom@conference.localhost" id="2725765463385791444">
   <event xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event">
      <items node="urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:messages">
         <item id="2725765463385791444">
            <message xmlns="jabber:client" xml:lang="en" to="user1@localhost" from="myroom@conference.localhost/user1" type="groupchat">
               <apply-to xmlns="urn:xmpp:fasten:0" id="358f5b60-3d10-11ea-be33-5f58c62bedc3">
                  <retract xmlns="urn:xmpp:message-retract:0" />
               </apply-to>
            </message>
         </item>
      </items>
   </event>
</message>
```

And when I query the history for the room, I receive this:

```html
<message xmlns="jabber:client" to="user1@localhost/395000986606606742032146" from="myroom@conference.localhost">
   <result xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:2" id="1579690081679918">
      <forwarded xmlns="urn:xmpp:forward:0">
         <message xmlns="jabber:client" xml:lang="en" from="myroom@conference.localhost/user1" type="groupchat">
            <x xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user">
               <item jid="user1@localhost/1132254315040517635831042" />
            </x>
            <archived xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:tmp" by="myroom@conference.localhost" id="1579690081679918" />
            <stanza-id xmlns="urn:xmpp:sid:0" by="myroom@conference.localhost" id="1579690081679918" />
            <urls />
            <origin-id xmlns="urn:xmpp:sid:0" id="358f5b60-3d10-11ea-be33-5f58c62bedc3" />
            <body>9</body>
         </message>
         <delay xmlns="urn:xmpp:delay" from="conference.localhost" stamp="2020-01-22T10:48:01.679918Z" />
      </forwarded>
   </result>
</message>
```

**What am I missing? Shouldn't I receive something like a [tombstone](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0424.html#tombstones) of the message?**

So far, my settings are:

- ejabberd 19.09.1
- Using the [MucSub](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/xmpp-clients-bots/extensions/muc-sub/) approach
- [mod_man](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#mod-mam) is configured
- Persisting with MySQL 5.7
- strophe.js 1.3.4

And this is my ejabberd.yml:

```js
hosts:
  - "localhost"

loglevel: 4
log_rotate_size: 10485760
log_rotate_date: ""
log_rotate_count: 1
log_rate_limit: 100

certfiles:
  - "/etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/fullchain.pem"
  - "/etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/privkey.pem"

ca_file: "/etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/cacert.pem"

sql_type: mysql
sql_server: "localhost"
sql_database: "ejabberd"
sql_username: "ejabberd"
sql_password: "****"
sql_port: 3306

auth_method: sql
default_db: sql

listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: false
  -
    port: 5269
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 524288
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      "/admin": ejabberd_web_admin
      "/api": mod_http_api
      "/bosh": mod_bosh
      "/captcha": ejabberd_captcha
      "/upload": mod_http_upload
###      "/ws": ejabberd_http_ws
      "/oauth": ejabberd_oauth
  -
    port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/admin": ejabberd_web_admin
      "/websocket": ejabberd_http_ws
  -
    port: 1883
    ip: "::"
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000

s2s_use_starttls: optional

acl:
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
      - ::1/128
      - ::FFFF:127.0.0.1/128
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin@localhost"

access_rules:
  local:
    allow: local
  c2s:
    deny: blocked
    allow: all
  announce:
    allow: admin
  configure:
    allow: admin
  muc_create:
    allow: admin
  pubsub_createnode:
    allow: local
  trusted_network:
    allow: loopback

api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      access:
        allow:
          acl: loopback
          acl: admin
      oauth:
        scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        access:
          allow:
            acl: loopback
            acl: admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      ip: 127.0.0.1/8
    what:
      - status
      - connected_users_number

shaper:
  normal: 1000
  fast: 50000

shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    5000: admin
    100: all
  c2s_shaper:
    none: admin
    normal: all
  s2s_shaper: fast

max_fsm_queue: 10000

acme:
   contact: "mailto:admin@localhost"
   ca_url: "https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org"

modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {}
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_fail2ban: {}
  mod_http_api: {}
  mod_http_upload:
    put_url: https://@HOST@:5443/upload
  mod_last: {}
  mod_mam:
    ## Mnesia is limited to 2GB, better to use an SQL backend
    ## For small servers SQLite is a good fit and is very easy
    ## to configure. Uncomment this when you have SQL configured:
    db_type: sql
    assume_mam_usage: true
    default: always
  mod_mqtt: {}
  mod_muc:
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_mam:
      - allow
    default_room_options:
      allow_query_users: false
      allow_subscription: true  # enable MucSub
      mam: true
      persistent: true
      public: false
      public_list: false
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_proxy65:
    access: local
    max_connections: 5
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - flat
      - pep
    force_node_config:
      ## Avoid buggy clients to make their bookmarks public
      storage:bookmarks:
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  mod_register:
    ## Only accept registration requests from the "trusted"
    ## network (see access_rules section above).
    ## Think twice before enabling registration from any
    ## address. See the Jabber SPAM Manifesto for details:
    ## https://github.com/ge0rg/jabber-spam-fighting-manifesto
    ip_access: trusted_network
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_vcard: {}
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version:
    show_os: false


### Local Variables:
### mode: yaml
### End:
### vim: set filetype=yaml tabstop=8
```

I apologize for the long message, but it provides the context.

Comment: Does your server [support XEP-0424](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0424.html#disco)?

Comment: @Flow, I'm using ejabberd 19.09.1 Community. After you asked, I accessed their page (https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/protocols/) and I think it is not supported in its core.

Answer (score 0):

Currently ejabberd does not support XEP-0424 so this won't work.